# Do non-English academic journals pay for a translated paper?

Tags: journals, translations

I am currently a PhD student in mathematics with a very strong interest in foreign languages (native language English), and I would be interested in translating math articles in foreign languages into English on the side.

Is this something that academic journals are generally willing to pay for? How would one go about finding work in this area?

Comment: I don't see why a journal would need this, unless it's intended as a direct translation (such as [JETP](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/)) of a journal in another language to English. If it is, then of course they might be interested, but you'd have to ask the individual journals about this.

Comment: @aeismail Maybe it's not the journals themselves who are interested. It seems like there is a lot of interest in having Russian scientific journals translated into English, but then I'm not sure where to ask about finding that kind of freelance work

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a translator looking for work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'd have a better chance of getting more reliable information if you go to popular online forums for translators like [ProZ](http://www.proz.com/) and [TranslatorsCafé](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/), where you can talk to professional translators and browse job ads. A very quick search already gave me one recent (but already closed) ad that seems to be looking for a translator for an academic journal:

http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/job146043.htm

> I am currently in search of French to English Translator with a mathematics & engineering background to translate an academic journal.

Also, AMS seems to have a list of translated journals here:

http://www.ams.org/msnhtml/trnjor.pdf

Anyway, there seems to be a demand for that kind of job, so you might be able to find a job if you know where to look. So, maybe the question is more about how to become a professional translator (and find jobs) than about academia.